# cropper.js Create crop-area around left click location?

Tags: javascript, cropper, cropperjs

I have cropper.js working well when the user clicks and drags over an area of the image.

How could I have cropper.js crop an area of the image when the user simply clicks on a portion of the image?

For example, wherever the user clicks, a 50x50 'crop-box' area would be created around that clicked x,y position.

As it stands currently, I can use the .setCropData() method to set the crop box's position and dimensions, but I can only get it to "fire" as part of the cropend event.

The cropstart event seems like an ideal place for this, as it captures the initial mousedown event, but I can't get the setCropData() method to fire as part of this event.

From what I can tell, in order for cropper.js to do anything, it must progress through a chain of events: from cropstart, to crop, then eventually to cropend. Which means the mouse must be dragged in some direction. If the user simply *clicks* the mouse and that's it, with no further drag motion, only the cropstart event will fire.

For example, as something simple for test purposes, this is not working:

```
    cropstart: function(event) {
      let $canvas = $('#canvas-' + $cropperImageIdNumber);

      cropperInstance.setCropBoxData({left: 100, top: 100, width: 50, height: 50});

      console.log('cropstart CropBoxData');
      console.log(cropperInstance.getCropBoxData({}));
    },
```

After clicking the mouse, the console log reports seemingly empty cropBoxData, and no crop is drawn onto the image. I suspect this is because, without a crop event technically started, there's nothing yet to set.

However, if I take that same thing and put it as part of the cropend event, it works as expected. The difference though, is that I cannot just "click", but must actually drag a crop box of any size:

```
    cropend: function(event) {
      cropperInstance.cropped = true;

      let $canvas = $('#canvas-' + $cropperImageIdNumber);
      cropperInstance.setCropBoxData({left: 100, top: 100, width: 50, height: 50});

      console.log('cropend CropBoxData');
      console.log(cropperInstance.getCropBoxData({}));
```

Any ideas how I can get cropper to "go through the motions" by setting the dimensions manually, but by way of a click rather than the usual drag? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you check the documentation? https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/master/README.md#setcropboxdatadata

Comment: @sjahan, I updated the OP with more detail. Would you mind taking a second look?